# How can I integrate the derivative of my tangent vector in a parametric curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I have the symbolic representation of a parametric curve, of its first and second derivatives and of the Frenet-Serret vectors.

However, what I would like to make is to integrate a normal vector following the curve without any torsion as given by Frenet normal and binormal vectors when curvature is reversed (see picture).[image]

To make it clearer : I'm drawing this "pipe" by connecting ellipses aligned on the frenet vectors. However, when curvature reverses, it makes an unnecessary torsade in my "pipe" because the normal and binormal vectors, both turn 180°.

So, I'd like to build 2 other vectors (instead of normal and binormal), which would keep the same orientation.

My tangent vector is the derivative of my position (x(t), y(t), z(t)) => (d(x(t))/dt, d(y(t))/dt, d(z(t))/dt). I have calculated the second derivative (d²(x(t))/dt², d²(y(t))/dt², d²(z(t))/dt²), so I would say that my tangent vector is some integral of the second derivative, and in the same logic, I inferred that I should be able to find another form of the integral my second derivative, which should be able to integrate that function to see what becomes a normal vector at the point t. But at this point, I feel blocked and I can't see how to continue the reasoning.

reply to @Tedshifrin : Those are (approximated) ellipses : Here is what you see with (approximated) circles [image]

Comment: Circles, not ellipses. Following the curve without any torsion? Explain precisely what you mean. Do you really mean the trace of a normal vector field that stays in a single plane?

Comment: Are you looking for the Bishop frame?

Comment: hmmm... It might be it. I'm trying to find publication about it...

Comment: I found the terms "rotation minimizing frames" which seems to be what I'm looking for. However, it's quite hard to find info about it (especially in french - this is not even mentioned in the french wikipedia) and since my knowledge of differential geometry is quite basic and mostly self taught. Could you point me to some simple explanation about how to build a Bishop Frame ? I would probably need to be able to express the vectors as functions of t in order to code it in openSCAD.

Comment: If you have access to JStor, [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319846) is the link to Bishop's original paper. For just the definition, see Exercise 11 on p. 33 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: I currently do not have access to jstor but I got it somewhere else and I checked your text, @TedShifrin. However I have a hard time figuring out a streamlined step by step method to build it from those theorems and definition. As mentioned before, I never completed a differential geometry cursus and I managed to compute the Frenet frame because I could understand it in terms of vectors, simple derivatives and vector product. However, I managed to find an satisfying solution to my problem, but I doubt it is a Bishop's frame : M1 = T x (0, 0, 1) and M2 = T x M1.

Answer (score 1):

Some people suggested in the comments that I might need the Bishop's frame, but since my differential geometry knowledge is very basic, I failed to understand how to build it from the papers I found/received.

However, I managed to build a satisfying frame which solved the torsion problem observed with Frenet-Serret frame. It might not be perfect, but it is much better. The method to build it consists in

- building a first orthogonal vector as the cross product of the tangent vector with a unitary vertical vector (It's OK, because my function never get purely vertical): m1 = T x (0, 0, 1)
- norming it: M1 = m1/|m1|
- building the second vector as the cross product of the tangent vector and M1 : M2 = T x M1

Here is the result :
[image]
[image]